# How to force kinect to a certain USB 2.0 BUS

Tags: kinect, usb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got laptop with 4 usb **BUS** inside, 3 of them are usb 2.0. And I have 4 usb ports on side of my laptop, 3 of them are usb 2.0 **PORT** and one is 3.0 port. I want to connect 2 kinects to 2 of my usb 2.0 **BUS**, But no matter which usb 2.0 **PORT** I connect the Kinects to, they alwas goes in the same usb 2.0 **BUS**, hence I can only get data out of one Kinect, since one kinect will cost the whole bandwidth of a usb 2.0 **BUS**.

here's my lsusb results:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 017: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 002 Device 018: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
Bus 002 Device 019: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Bus 002 Device 020: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5205 IMC Networks 
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 021: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 002 Device 022: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
Bus 002 Device 023: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Bus 002 Device 024: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
```

I want to force one kinect to use BUS 01 instead of BUS 02, but I don't know how. Any suggestions? Where can I find more information on that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31736/how-to-force-kinect-to-a-certain-usb-2.0-bus/) by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

USB ports are physically connected to one bus or another, and there's no way to change that. The ThinkPads I've worked with have had each port on a separate bus. If your laptop vendor decided to put all of your USB ports on the same bus, then you're probably out of luck.

If you have an expansion slot, you may be able to install a USB card in it and get another USB bus that way.

You might try one kinect on the USB 3.0 bus if you're desperate, but it hasn't worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on 2012-04-12**:
kinect simplely don't work with usb 3.0 for now. Thanks for your answer anyway, but it seems I'm no luck on this. My laptop doesn't have any expansion ability.